# Bool pointer in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, boolean

Given the following method:

`- (void)doThingWith:(NSString *)string changeBoolean:(BOOL *)booleanPointer
{
    // Do Something
    *booleanPointer = NO;
}`

How am I supposed to translate that to Swift?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would be equivalent, however i'm not sure how you intend on using the 'NSString' variable, so I have omitted 'inout'.

```
func doThingWith( string : String, inout changeBool : Bool ) {
    //Do Something
    changeBool = false
}
```

Comment: The string isn't useful. I just wrote it as part as the method. Thanks!